# In Linux how to add a build step in Qt Creator that uses su privileges without getting the wrong password attempts on builds?

Tags: ubuntu, qt-creator, sudo, qmake

My goal is to successfully link a folder to /opt/ directory- which needs to be run with sudo.

I have tried this:

```
 system(sudo ln -s $$OUT_PWD/xampp /opt/lampp):message("You should manually link LAMPP")
```

But building from qt-creator it does not prompt for sudo password, therefore I couldn't get it to link the folder. I got the "wrong password attempts..." error in the Compiler Output. Then I tried these with build steps:

```
make
sudo make install
```

to see if it would prompt me there, but it failed on `make install` step with the same error, which is this in detail:

```
00:31:20: Starting: "/usr/bin/sudo" make install
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
00:31:20: The process "/usr/bin/sudo" exited with code 1.
```

The `system()` function in the qmake script works fine when I use `qmake && make && make install` from terminal since it prompts me before `sudo ln...` command; but for fast testing purposes I feel that building with CTRL-B inside Qt Creator should also work with sudo commands...

Is there a way to be prompted from Qt Creator, or a way around this? Like storing the sudo pass within the Qt Creator (although it is risky)... Or maybe making it run build steps on a terminal where it would prompt me? Would `prompt()` function in qmake work with gathering sudo passwords?

Any suggestions are welcome...

Comment: Can you build from gnome-terminal? I'm not sure how you would integrate a build step in Qt-Creator that requires elevated privileges. It would probably be easier to build from the terminal anyway. You could easily make a bash script that does all the build steps including qmake, make, and make install.

Comment: Yes, I can build from gnome-terminal. Thank you for the suggestion, I was thinking that a bash script would be easier too... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of research:

```
ssh-askpass Sudo Password | sudo -S bash ./script
```

Worked like a charm, it asks for the password in a separate window/prompt box. I added it under custom build steps. The important thing is to let `sudo` know that it will expect a password input via `-S` option.

```
echo "password" | sudo -S bash ./script
```

Also works with bash scripts, however as you might think it is insecure storing the sudo password inside the script. It is said that read permissions should fix that issue.

Answer (score 2):

@Logan You can cause `sudo` to use the `ssh-askpass` (GUI password request dialog) directly with its `-A` option, this can use the `SUDO_ASKPASS` environmental variable to override a `/usr/bin/ssh-askpass` value that may be configured in `/etc/sudo.conf`<sup>[1]</sup> (like the suggestions of `gksudo` or `kdesudo` from @herophuong ). This gets around the security risk of the second solution in your answer that leaves the `"password"` visible to anything that can observe the commandline arguments. The equivalent to your first solution becomes:

```
sudo -A -s ./script
```

Don't forget that `sudo` may provide credential caching so that, if it has been used *very* recently (default 5 minutes?), a repeated invocation uses that cached password value instead of making another password request.  *If, for sanity/security reasons, this is not desired for a script (or elsewhere) use `sudo -K` with no other arguments to immediately clear any cached credentials (no password is needed for that usage) so that any subsequent `sudo` usage **will** require authentication.*

<sub>1 - Remember to use `visudo` as root if you wish to edit `/etc/sudo.conf` to add:</sub>

```
# Path to askpass helper program
Path askpass /usr/bin/ssh-askpass
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in a comment by Cameron Tinker you can set up Qt Creator to have a deploy step with the command gnome-terminal and arguments -e "sudo make install".

Effectively the same as running `gnome-terminal -e "sudo make install"`

Image is a screenshot of what this config looks like in Qt Creator :)

[Qt Creator with sudo make install step with gnome terminal project settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM5VB.png)

[image]

`gksudo` is no longer recommended or installed by default on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `gksudo` (in GNOME) or `kdesudo` (in KDE). The commands will then use a window to prompt for your password.